# MySQL: How To Convert Text In To Varchar

Tags: mysql, database, varchar

I and one of my friends were working on a simple project I know front-end and he was working on the back-end now when only two days are remaining to submit the project, I messed up a little bit I accidentally changed some SQL code/Database and the login isn't working.

Now I want to fix it before the other even knows about it. for that, I have checked a few questions on Stack Overflow and also tried searching for the solution on google but all in vain.

-- Dumping data for table `admin`

```
INSERT INTO `admin` (`id`, `login_name`, `login_pass`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'cc422cddb6d31a2e2c2ab4f2ca58761d', 'letMEinn0w', 'imroot');
```

I want the `'login_pass' = (letMEinn0w)` to be converted in Varchar and look like `'login_name' = (cc422cddb6d31a2e2c2ab4f2ca58761d)`

Comment: If you're asking how to encrypt/hash the incoming password (a good thing), then we'll need more information, such as the relevant application code.

Comment: How did you get value `cc422cddb6d31a2e2c2ab4f2ca58761d` for login name?

Comment: You are looking for what? Question is unclear.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it was the other guy who did this

Comment: @kish i want to encrypt the password into varchar

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The app is php based and code above is form the .sql database file

Comment: This article may help you https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/